# How to publish data changes between databases within RabbitMQ?

Tags: database, service, architecture, rabbitmq, message-queue

Suppose we have two applications `A` and `B` with their own different databases `A1` (MySQL) and `B1` (Postgres) correspondingly. We create entities `X` and `Y` associated with each other in application `A`. `Y` belongs to `X`. On every insert to database `A1` (after commit) we publish message to RabbitMQ to make application `B` aware of brand new entities. One event per entity – `X1` and `Y1`. Everything is good, if RabbitMQ keeps the order of the messages, so workers in application `B` may process `X1` first and `Y1` second to establish right association between new `A` and `B` records in database `B1`. But as far as I understand RabbitMQ is not intended to keep messages order and does it in very specific circumstances, like publish within one channel, send to one exchange, push to one queue, consume within one channel.

So my question is about the correct direction and general approach:

1. Should I choose another message queue, that guarantees messages order?
2. Have I missed something specific in RabbitMQ messages order specifics?
3. Should I implement some kind of retry mechanism in application `B` side, that will re-enqueue messages back to RabbitMQ in case if message order was not as expected?

Maybe it will give more sensible context – `B1` is a data warehouse, that aggregates data not only from `A1`, but also other databases.

Comment: I want to build feature with same functionality in my .NET application using MS SQL server.  But stuck at how I will track change of database changes and trigger the rabbitMQ message. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Everything is good, if RabbitMQ keeps the order of the messages

Is that the only solution?
Can't X and Y instances get a sequence number assigned, which will then be used to rebuild the right sequence within B?

> to establish right association between new A and B records

Can't X1, Y1 express an explicit relation allowing a creation of A, B without relying on sequence?

The point is:
Message ordering is always expensive. You either have hard constraints (e.g. one consumer) or you have less availability and speed. Your best bet is finding a way to not rely on order.